# Refactoring conditional statements PHP

Tags: php, refactoring

I did make a User class with an post method with large if-elseif statement like this:

```
class Users
{
    public static function  post($request)
    {
        if ($request[0] == 'register') {
            return self::register();
        } elseif ($request[0] == 'login') {
            return self::login();
        } elseif ($request[0] == 'pass') {
            return self::changePass();
        } elseif ($request[0] == 'avatar') {
            return self::updateAvatar();
        } elseif ($request[0] == 'logout') {
            return self::logout();
        }
        throw new Excepcion....;
    }

    private static function register()
    {
        //Return something
    }
    private static function login()
    {
        //Return something
    }
    private static function changePass()
    {
        //Return something
    }
    private static function updateAvatar()
    {
        //Return something
    }
    private static function logout()
    {
        //Return something
    }
}
```

I already tried wit this:

```
public static function post($request)
  {
    $method = $request[0];  
    return self::{$method}();
  }
```

But PHPMD send a warning Avoid Unused Private Method

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Depending on how important the PHPMD messages are, you could see if you can use suppress them for methods you know are called (https://phpmd.org/documentation/suppress-warnings.html may help)

Comment: Hi @NigelRen I'm a fan of the clean code so it is very important to me

Comment: What is your precise question?

Comment: Hi @ArSeN, the precise question is: Is there any way to refactor the use of if statements (or switch), which is different from what I stated in the question? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You receive a "Avoid Unused Private Method" warning because you are calling a private method within a static method.

try:

```
<?php

class Users {

    public function post($request) {
        $method = $request[0];
        return $this->{$method}();
    }

    private function register() {
        //Return something
    }

    private function login() {
        //Return something
    }

    private function changePass() {
        //Return something
    }

    private function updateAvatar() {
        //Return something
    }

    private function logout() {
        //Return something
    }

}

?>
```

Call:

```
$r = (new Users())->post($request);
```

Comment: Hello @Miqueas Francisco. I receive a "Avoid Unused Private Method" warning because i never call the method by name (i use self::{$method}), PHPMD assume that I declare a method and never use it, but the really question is how to refactor the use of if statements in a different way from what i stated in the question. Thanks for your reply